# JavaScript, передача из input в js обработка и передача в div

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Всем привет, странный вопрос. Попытаюсь описать
У меня есть input в который можно вводить только числа и есть span в котором нужно отобразить данных из input умноженные допустим на 3.
Мне нужно когда мы вводим число в input, допустим 100, это число передавалась в js там умножалась на 3 и выводился конечный результат 300.

Я пытался сделать это таким образом но выводит 0:

```
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function() {
                            var sum = document.getElementById("bet-input").value;
                            document.getElementById("sum-discount").innerHTML = (sum * 3); 
                        }, false );
```

Comment: Потому как нужно отлавливать изменение инпута, а этот код выполнится один раз при загрузке страницы, когда там ничего не было.

Answer (score 2):

так попробуйте

```
document.getElementById("bet-input").addEventListener( "change", function() {
                        var sum = document.getElementById("bet-input").value;
                        document.getElementById("sum-discount").innerHTML = (sum * 3); 
                    }, false );
```

Comment: Я заметил что все стали добавлять в метод `addEventListener` в качестве третьего аргумента `false`, в связи с чем это сделано?

Comment: useCapture Необязательный
Если равно true, useCapture указывает, что пользователь желает начать захват.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: Note: useCapture не всегда был опциональным. Лучше указывать данный параметр для повышения совместимости.

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.getElementById("bet-input").addEventListener("input", function() {
  var sum = this.value;
  document.getElementById("sum-discount").innerHTML = (sum * 3);
});
```

```html
<input id="bet-input" />
<span id="sum-discount"></span>
```

Comment: Игорь будем соревноваться в написании одинаковых ответов

Comment: Идея ведь одна и таже